# nginx encoding of the URL

Tags: django, url, nginx, amazon-ec2, webserver

I'm creating a django app with nginx in a production environment.

When I navigate to different pages on my wite, I get 400 - Bad Request errors. This is what the URL will look like in the browser.

```
http://54.158.154.23:8000/%7B$%%20url%20'members:member_signup'%20%%7D
```

But when I manually go into the browser address bar and take away all the needless characters....

```
http://54.158.154.23:8000/url'members:member_signup'
```

Then the page renders perfectly!

Here is my app's nginx config file:

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
   # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 54.172.211.18 172.31.38.120 unclique.io 54.158.154.23; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste


    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /path/to/your/mysite/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ec2-user/UnClique/UnClique/static/; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }


    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass unix://tmp/uwsgi.sock;
        include     /home/ec2-user/UnClique/config/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }

}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to make requests map to the actual URL? The code is clearly breaking because django isn't matching any of those extra characters (%, letters, and numbers) to the URL Patterns and therefore nginx throws me a 400 Error.

54.158.154.23 is the ip address of the current EC2 that I'm using.

**UPDATE**

Code that calls the url:

```
def late_registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.member.preferred_name = form.cleaned_data.get('preferred_name')
            user.member.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            user.member.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user.member.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.member.classification = form.cleaned_data.get('classification')
            user.member.major = form.cleaned_data.get('major')
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('members:member_home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'members/signup_form.html', {'form': form})
```

The HTML template being called in the render function

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Welcome
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Late Registration....a Classic</h1>
            <br>
            <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can I see the code that you call a url?

Comment: I'll update the post @MohammadAli